# AWS CodeBuild ECR CannotPullContainerError

Tags: aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

CodeBuild project fails at the Provisioning phase due to the following error

```
BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's container image. CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for <image-name>, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: arn:aws:sts::<id>
```

[image]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The issue was with the Image Pull credentials.
CodeBuild was using default AWS CodeBuild credentials for pulling the image while the ECRAccessPolicy was attached to the Project Service Role.

I fixed it by updating the image pull credentials to use project service role.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @chaitanya-bapta. For anyone else having trouble finding where to edit these settings for an existing build project, you need to select *Environment* in the *Edit* menu of the build project, then select *Override image*, then select the *Custom image* radio button, and select your "Environment type". The ECR options will then appear below.

Comment: omg.. so much time wasted debugging my codebuild service role permissions, only to eventually give up and google this, to find out it wasnt using the service role... thanks much.

Comment: The UI is changed a little bit, but it works for me

Answer (score 8):

fwiw I stumbled across this issue when using `terraform` to create my codebuild pipeline.

The setting to change for this was `image_pull_credentials_type` which should be set to `SERVICE_ROLE` rather than `CODEBUILD` in the `environment` block of the `resource "aws_codebuild_project"`.

Thank you to Chaitanya for the response which pointed me in this direction with the accepted answer.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31234486)

Comment: To clarify - I added my answer to expand upon Chaitanya's answer. Their answer was how to use the AWS console to fix this, however, this issue could occur in a system built with terraform, which is why I added my answer.

Comment: To provide further detail, this change is only needed when using an image hosted in a private repository to which you need to authenticate (like ECR), and NOT when using an AWS managed image like the default AL2 Linux image.

Answer (score 7):

To add additional clarity (not enough reputation yet to comment on an existing answer), the CodeBuild project service role needs to have the following permissions if trying to pull from a private repository:

```
{
   "Action":[
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
   ],
   "Effect":"Allow",
   "Resource":[
      "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:repository/REPOSITORY_NAME*"
   ]
}
```

Also, the ECR repository policy should also look something like this (scope down root if desired):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to add the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken for that policy above.

Comment: I tried this but not working, getting the same error as above. I also tried with all permission as given here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecr_repository_policy

Any suggestion please?

Comment: @bhattraideb An easy way to check is (if in a dev environment), to give the calling role ecr:*. You can also take a look at CloudTrail and search for access denied in the error columns to see what permissions might be missing. Lastly, if pulling from ECR, always check the permissions of the repo itself to ensure it is providing access to the role trying to pull the image.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom image, I had to select "Other ECR Account" and paste the URI of the image in my ECR. Also had to enable "Privleged" flag.

Even though I am accessing it from the same account.